# Question about note stopping

Tags: piano, notation, sheet-music

When I play one note in piano, and play another after that, the latter makes the first silent. Does a particular note stops when another note is played , especially in piano?

Comment: Not on any piano I've ever played! What make/model? Surely not an acoustic piano?

Comment: This is #3 in a series of really confused questions - https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/89715/note-durations-in-instruments and https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/89687/2-notes-played-at-the-same-time

Comment: On an electronic keyboard that lacks polyphonics (i.e., it can only play one note at a time), that's exactly what happens.  As Tim pointed out, an acoustic piano can play 88 notes simultaneously.

Comment: Hi,  when you post a question, please try to be as detailed as possible.  In addition to the questions in the other comments,  are you holding keys down, and do you have a sustain pedal on your piano?

Comment: It *may* just be that you have an electronic keyboard, and it's set to play only one note at a time - some have this arrangement on certain sounds. Check with the instructions - reset to **polyphony**.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you're theoretically supposed to stop playing a note at the end of its nominal duration.  In most music another note is written at exactly that point, but there's no rule that requires this.  So if there's a piece with a metronome mark setting the quarter note at sixty beats per minute, you play the quarter note for one second, regardless of what comes after it.  Theoretically.

I say "theoretically" because musical interpretation and expression may lead a performer to shorten or lengthen a note slightly, or more than slightly.  Sometimes this is in response to an articulatory or expressive mark made by the composer, and sometimes it comes from the performer's own sensibilities.

When you're playing the piano, each note you play stops sounding when you lift the key, unless you're using a pedal (other than the soft pedal).